# Rigging Error "Bone Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones"

Tags: rigging

I want to connect bone with the mesh with automatic weights but when I press Ctrl+P->With automatic weights it brings me this error , I tried to remove doubles but the error hasn`t gone .

[image]

Comment: Last time I had the same problem,this tutorial helped me. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZPqxADetWE

Comment: For me I just had to increase the number of vertices in my model and it worked!
Subsurf modifier works well :)

Comment: Could you upload the .blend file to make it easier to assess http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

removee doubles

recalculate

remove all modifier

place the root bone to the center of the model

apply the subsurface modifier and parent them

apply the decimate planar modifier
Posible this will help?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem for me... I scaled, rotated and moved the mesh and the skeleton in object mode. Meaning the object center of both of them doesnt match. Set the position and rotation in object mode on all axis to 0 and set the scale to 1 (for both skeleton and mesh) Go to edit mode move your mesh and rig around and make everything fit. Now go back to object mode make sure position, rotaion and scale are still the same for mesh and skeleton... if so you should be able to parent your stuff properly.﻿